# Reject carrier calls, accept SIP calls

Tags: sms, calls, call-screening, sip, sms-blocking

I've gone the route of a data only plan (tablet plan) on my smart phone and am using the services of a VOIP provider. Things are going nicely, just trying to iron out a few details.

When you order a mobile data plan, you get a SIM card and matching phone number. On a tablet you can't receive calls or texts, but on a phone you can. If you do, you pay the premium price.

Android natively provides a SIP client in the phone app. Android also provides a Blacklist option and the use of wildcards. Allows me to block some or all calls and texts. However, it doesn't allow me to distinguish between a call to my SIP account or to my mobile number (unless somebody here knows how).

Nobody knows my mobile data plan number, but I do get the occasional "wrong number". I imagine that I could also receive an occasional SMS (also wrong number or for advertising).

So, does the Android Phone allow me to block calls and sms from the carrier, but allow calls from the SIP client? As in: block incoming calls that are *to* a number, not *from* like in a blacklist.

I know I could block all calls and sms with the phone app and use a separate VOIP app for SIP calls. However, I wish to know if this is possible with the native applications.

Comment: On incoming calls, do you get charged even if you don't pick up the phone?  How about inbound SMS, does your carrier charge you for inbound ones?  Does your plan offer call forwarding (and if so, is it free or paid?)

Comment: No I don't get charged if I don't pick up. However, when I'm not paying attention I might pick up. A SIP call shows the account, a normal carrier call does not. Thats how you distinguish the two, but you have to pay attention. Not always the case. I don't know if I'm charged for incoming SMSs, but would be great if I could block them too since that number "doesn't/shouldn't exist".

Comment: Does your carrier offer call forwarding? If so, will they charge if you forward all calls to your SIP number?

Comment: I don't know, but I wouldn't want this anyway. The number I get through the plan is not a number I wish to share. I already have a number. Moreover, if I do get a call on that number, it is most likely a wrong number. So forwarding wrong numbers is out of the question.

Comment: You could forward the calls to another SIP number that doesn't ring through to your phone.  If you're in the US, Google Voice gives you a free number, and is by far the easiest to set up.  Alternatively, there are a myriad other SIP services that offer a free number.

Comment: Oh, now I understand where you were going with that. Good idea! I could forward the number to the carrier's voicemail service -- which in fact doesn't exist on my plan, but would give me the desired outcome. However, I get a call forwarding icon in the task bar. Wish I could hide it since this is a permanent solution.

Comment: Thought it was a good idea at first, but it seems that Android is forwarding ALL calls received (carrier + SIP calls).

Comment: It may be because you are doing it via settings in your Phone app. Try activating the forwarding by dialing a special access code. E.g. on Verizon it's *72. Open dialer, dial *725551231212 and press Send. (where 555 is the area code, and 123-1212 is the number)  I think that may even get rid of the "Forwarding" icon from notification bar.

Comment: It is indeed *72 + number, but there's a message saying I must do this from the phone menu (rolls eyes). I also called the carrier and asked to block incoming calls. No dice, but they were able to block incoming SMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the carrier to block the voice and SMS on the SIM card

Comment: Yes I realize that, but was wondering if Android could do it for me. That way it's always blocked even if I change carriers. I might revert to that solution in the end if no other options are presented. Cheers.

Comment: Just checked with the carrier, they say they cannot. I will be trying with another carrier, but nonetheless would love to do it myself :-)